# Defaulting a DateTimePicker's date to one in the past

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker

In a windows Forms app, I'm trying to set the value of a DateTimePicker component to a bunch of months in the past so I don't have to do it manually each time to test a date range. I'm trying this in the form's constructor right after InitializeComponent():

dateTimePickerFrom.Value.AddMonths(-15);

...but the value is still the current date when I run the form. What do I need to do to tell it that I'm really serious about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing this?

```
dateTimePickerFrom.Value = dateTimePickerFrom.Value.AddMonths(-15);
```

Answer (score 4):

Non-tsted Demo Example: Try this after you initialize the component:

```
dateTimePickerFrom.Value = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-15);
```